# Storing end pointer to uninitialized array in constexpr context

Tags: c++, arrays, c++20, constexpr, unions

I'm trying to create a constexpr friendly small buffer optimized vector type that stores a begin, end and capacity pointer as usual, but when it is default constructed the begin and capacity pointer point towards local memory before reallocating to heap when required. However I cannot figure out how to store the capacity pointer in the constexpr context, because I want it to be able to support non-trivially constructed types. In order to store non-trivially constructed types I cannot use std::aligned_storage because of the full type erasure which will not allow me to get the elements later (because reinterpret_cast is not allowed), so I decided to store the elements in an array of unions (kind of like optional does it). Storing it like this allows me to get the elements later through union access and allows me to leave the array uninitialized, but i cannot figure out how to store a value pointer to capacity end when it is stored inside of unions because it does not detect the whole one beyond last pointer stuff when pointing to a union value. Ofcourse all of this requires c++20.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

struct Null{};

template<typename T>
union Storage
{
    Null uninitialized;
    T value;

    constexpr Storage()
    : uninitialized{}
    {}

    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr Storage(Args&&... args)
    : value(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}

    constexpr ~Storage(){}
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct Vec
{
    std::array<Storage<T>, N> storage;

    T* begin; 
    T* end;   

    constexpr Vec()
    : begin(makeBegin())
    , end(makeEnd())
    {}

    constexpr T* makeBegin()
    {
        return &storage[0].value;
    }
    constexpr T* makeEnd()
    {
        return (&storage[N].value);
    }
};


constexpr bool test()
{
    Vec<std::pair<float, float>, 10> vec{};

    for(auto it = vec.begin; it < vec.end; ++it)
    {
        std::construct_at(it, 10.0f, 10.0f);
    }

    return vec.begin[5] == std::pair{ 10.0f, 10.0f };
}


int main()
{
    static_assert(test());
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/46o19qcvP

Is there another way to get a pointer to stored non-trivially constructible types like pairs in an array without initializing them?

Comment: (1) There is no array of `T` anywhere, so pointer arithmetic and indexing through `Vec<T>::begin` is UB. (2) An implementation is allowed to add padding to `Storage` as it sees fit. `option` doesn't care, but you cannot portably use the same trick to make an array.

Comment: I could ofcourse keep the pointer to the union itself as an iterator, but that would be kind of anoying in combination with the later used heap memory iterators in case it overflows. Is there any way to have it be stored as T pointers?

Comment: I don't think it is doable.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using your `Storage` `union` over an `std::variant` where the first type defined is the `std::monostate`.

Comment: Variant stores a type index aswell which I don't need. But if I have an array of variants I would still not be able to have iterators point to T's. It seems like using uninitialized arrays is much harder in constexpr than using constexpr new... Which will sort of force me to write 2 implementations one for consteval and one for not consteval

Comment: So you want iterators to only iterate through the `std::variant`'s that have been initialized and to return the initialized value, instead of the `std::variant` its self? Can items be inserted any where in the `std::array`? In other words, can `T`'s be stored in the `std::array` non-contiguously?

Comment: The problem with the whole union situation is that even then I'm not sure whether it's contiguous because it could still add padding etc. So this data structure woudn't really be very usefull, when for example, SIMD alignment is required or stuff like that. It's kind of weird how constexpr new and delete seems to be more supported now for storing uninitialized elements than when you want to do the same in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code:

- `T*` is not a valid iterator for your representation, as the `T`s are actually a member of a structure. The iterator needs to operate on the array's value type.
- Using `storage[N]` is an out of bounds access, even if you just try to use the address of the member within.

One way fix both problems is to use a custom iterator type. Here is an example based on your original code (the iterator implementation is a bit incompete - I just implemented what is needed to get the code to compile):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <array>


template<typename T>
union Storage
{
    T value;

    constexpr Storage() {}

    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr Storage(Args&&... args)
    : value(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}

    constexpr ~Storage(){}
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct Vec
{
    std::array<Storage<T>, N> storage;

    struct iterator {
        Storage<T>* p;
        constexpr T& operator*() { return this->p->value; }
        constexpr T* operator->() { return &this->p->value; }
        constexpr T& operator[](std::size_t n) { return (this->p)[n].value; }
        constexpr iterator& operator++() { ++this->p; return *this; }
        constexpr iterator  operator++(int) { auto rc(*this); ++*this; return rc; }
        constexpr iterator& operator+= (std::size_t n){ this->p += n; return *this; }
        friend constexpr iterator operator+ (iterator it, std::size_t n) { return it += n; }
        constexpr bool      operator== (iterator const&) const = default;
    constexpr bool      operator< (iterator const& other) const { return this->p < other.p; }
    };
    
    
    iterator begin; 
    iterator end;   
    
    constexpr Vec()
    : begin(makeBegin())
    , end(makeEnd())
    {}

    constexpr iterator makeBegin()
    {
        return {&this->storage[0]};
    }
    constexpr iterator makeEnd()
    {
        return this->makeBegin() + N;
    }
};


constexpr bool test()
{
    Vec<std::pair<float, float>, 10> vec{};

    for(auto it = vec.begin; it < vec.end; ++it)
    {
        std::construct_at(&*it, 10.0f, 10.0f);
    }

    return vec.begin[5] == std::pair{ 10.0f, 10.0f };
}


int main()
{   
    static_assert(test());
}
```

As the `T` elements need to be individually created to qualify as the active `union` member, here isn't really a way to get to store `T*` objects. The implication is that a potentially variable sized portion of a vector also stores `Storage<T>` elements to avoid messing with two different iterator types.

Comment: [Problem](https://godbolt.org/z/soqEq3nvh). I have no idea where the standard says so though.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: I see. I only tested with gcc-11.2.0 where it compiles. The error message raises the question how to _activate_ a `union` member. I suspect by constructing it which is what the `union` should inhibit in the first place. Possibly the best approach is to use the original custom iterator approach I had and making the external range also use the same `union` members: that didn't suffer from the same problem as the `union` member was activated by each individual construction.

Comment: Don't you have to initialize the entire array in one go here though? I don't think you can initialize one array element at a time here.

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe: yes, I think I agree. I shall restore my answer using a custom iterator. Of course, the implication is that the variable part of the array would also use the `union` representation which is a bit annoying but probably makes the overall handling of elements more consistent.

Comment: Kind of disapointing but I think this is the right answer. I geuss I will resort to using consteval new and delete in constexpr contexts.